# Flutter height size ListView.Builder in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter, listview

How to set the size of ListView.Builder ?

After several searches, my code looks like this:

My ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
                                physics:
                                    const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: listBenefits.length,
                                ,
                                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                  return MyWidget()
});
```

ListView.builder is wrapped in a column

```
Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [ListView.builder()]),
```

My column is wrapped in a container which is also wrapped in a column

```
AlertDialog(
      elevation: elevationAlertDialog,
      shape: shapeCard,
      scrollable: true,
      content: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: primaryColor),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
              ),
              child: Column()),
        ],
      ));
```

My AlertDialog has been called from :

```
showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
                    child: AlertDialog());
              },
            );
```

The result is an infinite ListView.builder, whereas I would like it to scale to the size of its children. Child size is obviously dynamic !

Anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SizedBox** for ListView Builder to set preferred size,

Example,

```
Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text("Some Element Before List View"),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext cont, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text("Test $index"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text("Some Element After List View"),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it's still not what I'm looking for.
The proposed solution gives me a ListView.builder of a specific size, but I don't need a specific size, but a size that fits the content of the ListView.builder!